# How to navigate to viewController from tableview cell, which is placed in other tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have placed a tableview2 in tableview1 Cell, Now when I click on the tableview2 cell I need to navigate to a new viewController. Please help me... I was struggling with one whole day :(

here is the code, the second table view is placed in SegmentedCell...
when i am trying to push, its unable to go next controller..

```
import UIKit
import XMSegmentedControl
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class segmentedCell: UITableViewCell, XMSegmentedControlDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let byndrColor : UIColor = UIColor( red: 224/255, green: 0/255, blue: 115/255, alpha: 1.0 )
let fontStyle = UIFont(name: "Lato-bold", size: 12)
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
var getApi = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 var course_id = String()
var materialListObjects = [MaterialsInSingleCourseGetSet]()
var assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects = [AssignmentAndExamsQuizGetSet]()




override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


    feedTableView.delegate = self
    feedTableView.dataSource = self

    segmentedControl.delegate = self
    segmentedControl.segmentTitle = ["LATEST", "MATERIALS", "COURSEWORK", "PROGRESS"]
    segmentedControl.font = fontStyle!
    segmentedControl.selectedItemHighlightStyle = XMSelectedItemHighlightStyle.BottomEdge
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    segmentedControl.tint = UIColor.black
    segmentedControl.highlightTint = byndrColor
    segmentedControl.highlightColor = byndrColor
    segmentedControl.edgeHighlightHeight = 2

    segmentedControl.selectedSegment = 0

 let share = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    materialListObjects = share.materialListInSingleCourse as! [MaterialsInSingleCourseGetSet]
    assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects = share.assignmentsExamsAndQuizListInSingleCourse as! [AssignmentAndExamsQuizGetSet]


    // Initialization code
}

func xmSegmentedControl(xmSegmentedControl: XMSegmentedControl, selectedSegment: Int) {

    if xmSegmentedControl == segmentedControl {
        print("SegmentedControl1 Selected Segment: \(selectedSegment)")
        switch  segmentedControl.selectedSegment
        {
        case 0:

           feedTableView.reloadData()
        case 1:
           feedTableView.reloadData()
        case 2:
            feedTableView.reloadData()
        case 3:
            feedTableView.reloadData()
        default :
            break
        }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 0
    {
    return 0
    }
    else
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 1
    {
        return materialListObjects.count
    }
    else
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 2
    {
        return assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects.count

    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 0
    {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TypeOneCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TypeOneCell
        return cell
    }
    else
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 1
        {

            if materialListObjects[indexPath.row].type == "file"
            {
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("materialCellOne", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! materialCellOne
                cell.materialNameLabel.text = materialListObjects[indexPath.row].title
                let image = materialListObjects[indexPath.row].title
                cell.contentImage.image = image.documentType(givenType: image)

                return cell
            }else
            {
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("materialCellTwo", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! materialCellTwo
                cell.materialNameLabel.text = materialListObjects[indexPath.row].title

                cell.contentImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "material_hyperlink")

                return cell
            }


        }
        else
            if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 2
            {
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CourseWorkCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CourseWorkCell
                print("assignment title : \(assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects[indexPath.row].title)")
                cell.titleLabel.text = assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects[indexPath.row].title
                if assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects[indexPath.row].type == ""
                {
                    cell.contentImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "assignment_large")
                }else
                {
                    cell.contentImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "exam_inline")
                }
                var time = assignmentExamAndQuizListObjects[indexPath.row].start
                time =  time.dateRange(dateString: time)
                time = time.days(givenDate: time)
                cell.timeLabel.text = time
                return cell
            }
            else
                if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 3
                {
                    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TypeOneCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TypeOneCell
                    return cell
                }
                else
                {
                    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TypeOneCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TypeOneCell
                    return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 2
    {
     return 70
    }
    else
    {
    return 100
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 150, height: 20))
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Heavy", size: 17)

    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 1
    {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        label.text = "All Materials"
    case 1:
        label.text = "From Your Courses"
    default:
        break
        }
    }
    else
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 2
    {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            label.text = "All CourseWork"
        case 1:
            label.text = "From Your Courses"
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }




    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

//How to perform from here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegment == 1
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
        let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuickLook") as! QuickLook


        if materialListObjects[indexPath.row].type == "url"
        {
            nextViewController.id = materialListObjects[indexPath.row].body
            nextViewController.type = "url"
        }
        else
        {
            nextViewController.id = materialListObjects[indexPath.row].id
        }
        nextViewController.course_id = String(describing: materialListObjects[indexPath.row].course_id)
        let naviControl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
        naviControl.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)



    }

}

}
```

Comment: Check tableview in didselectrow method and perform segue/ push

Comment: In `didselectrow` delegate, `if tableView == tableview2` then push

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show ur code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a similar scenario as yours and this is how you can get it working.

**1. `View Hierarchy`**

[image]

I have used **`tag`** property to uniquely identify both `UITableViews`, i.e.

1. Outer tableView tag = 0
2. Inner tableView tag = 1

**2.** Now implement **`UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`** methods for both the tableViews. Set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of both the tableViews as the `ViewController`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if tableView.tag == 0
    {
        return 1
    }
    else if tableView.tag == 1
    {
        return 5
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView.tag == 0
    {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "outercell", for: indexPath)
    }
    else if tableView.tag == 1
    {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "innercell", for: indexPath)
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView.tag == 1
    {
        //TODO: Write your code for navigating to another ViewController here
        print("Inner cell tapped")
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

In the `Interface Builder`, you can find a `tag` attribute corresponding to each element in the `attributes inspector`, i.e.

[image]

For `outer tableView` set it to `0` and for `inner tableView` set it to `1`.

Let me know if you still face any issues. Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you, i will try and let you know :)

Comment: it showing error like this "Illegal Configuration: The tableViewTwo outlet from the onClickCourse to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.
"

Comment: What outlet are you trying to connect?

Comment: I have added second tableview in first tableview cell same as which you have shown in the picture. when I am giving outlet to the second tableview to swift file it showing that error.

Comment: You cannot take the outlet of `second tableView` inside the `ViewControlle`r. Since the `second tableView` is added in the `UITableViewCell` which is a reusable entity and will be repeated, this is the reason you are getting "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" error. This was the reason I used `tag` property instead of outlet.

Comment: How to use tag property, I never used before

Comment: Thank you, Sure I will try. mostly it will be helpful.

Comment: Sure. Accept the answer if you get it working and let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: I am getting this exception when i am giving tags "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee9156ff8)"

Comment: Soo sorry its worked for me thanks!! How to mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: Just click the tick mark on the left side below arrow marks.

Comment: done!!  but one more doubt how to reload tableview2?

Comment: When do you want to reload it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController", sender: self);` in `didSelectrow` method of you tableView2.